# Firefox/Thunderbird won't download files/attachments

Tags: firefox, thunderbird

When I try to download/save files/attachments from Firefox/Thunderbird, I get a 0 byte file in my Downloads directory.

I have tried all possible permissions but no difference. In both cases, it works if I save to a folder outside my home directory (eg /tmp/downloads/) with the right permissions. My home directory is encrypted with fscrypt, not sure if this could be the issue.

This is on a fresh Disco minimal install. Firefox pre-installed, Thunderbird installed from default repositories. This issue doesn't affect any other programs.

Posted a bug report here but seems possibly not a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/1828011

Comment: fscrypt was set up using this guide: http://tlbdk.github.io/ubuntu/2018/10/22/fscrypt.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a confirmed bugs— you can see follow-up https://bugs.launchpad.net/firefox/+bug/1796661.

[Someone describe steps to reproduce the problem](https://bugs.launchpad.net/firefox/+bug/1796661/comments/6), the detail is very similar to yours.

> Steps to reproduce:
>
> I encrypted my homedir (on Ubuntu 18.04) with fscrypt following this
>   tutorial : https://tlbdk.github.io/ubuntu/2018/10/22/fscrypt.html
>   Then, I try to download any file from internet with Firefox in my
>   Download folder, in my homedir (or any encrypted folder).
>
> Actual results:
>
> The download instantly breaks. Only a 0kb file appears with the
>   correct name.
>
> Expected results:
>
> The file should be downloaded correctly.

The http://tlbdk.github.io site owner has explaining what might cause the bugs to occurs.

> The issue is because firefox does a rename from the `/tmp` folder to the
>   encrypted home folder, right now `fscrypt` returns `EPERM` instead of
>   `EXDEV` that would be normal when the operation can not complete because
>   of crossing a mount point or in this case unencrypted to an encrypted
>   folder.

Currently there's no proposed fix, so you can only wait.

A workaround is to bind /tmp to  a folder within your home directory (may cause other issues), or as a tmpfs. According to [this](https://github.com/google/fscrypt/issues/124), a fix from fscrypt has been merged into Linux 5.1

Comment: Thanks Jim, don't know how I missed that.
Not sure how much value my question adds, can delete it if need be, in the mean time accepting your answer.

Comment: For anyone else, I've got around this following tlbdk's suggestion (https://github.com/google/fscrypt/issues/76#issuecomment-456976770) by binding /tmp to a location in my home directory as follows: sudo mount -B ~/.tmp /tmp